# Why exactly does uBlock Origin not block Twitch ads lately?

Tags: ads, twitch.tv

Lately, Twitch has yet again become unusable. Every stream I load blasts these vile, loud ads at me, showing a little counter counting down until the actual stream is supposed to start.

Naturally, I always instinctively kill the tab immediately when it starts.

I've looked at the network tab in Pale Moon, and if I block what appears to be the vile ad video stream chunks, it shows a generic error message and doesn't display any video at all (not ad and not the stream itself).

However, it seems like people smarter than I could easily detect the little "counter" which appears to be a DOM element rather than baked into the video, and at the very least auto-mute and blank the screen while the ad is blasting.

But it's now been months of this and nothing has been done. I've tried looking all over for discussions/issues on this, but there's just outdated replies and no comments from anyone in charge or who has the ability to fix it.

Am I missing something? Isn't this kind of thing -- something very loud and obnoxious on a very major website -- exactly what typically spur these people to "take the challenge" and update the filters in some clever way? Or has Twitch somehow managed to prevent the blocking of these vile ads once and for all?

Answer (score 0):

> Why exactly does uBlock Origin not block Twitch ads lately?

Twitch has most likely changed the way their advertising code works. Content filter developers will have to reverse engineer the new javascripts that are playing the ads and neutralize any new countermeasures against blocking that Twitch might have been deployed.